# Can I alter DateFormat.SHORT to include seconds or something similar?

Tags: java, date-format

In my application I am using code like this:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
df.setTimeZone(User.getTimeZone());
String s = df.format(d);
```

to format dates in an application that is used across different locales.  I'd like to, sometimes, add seconds to this but I don't want to just specify one specific format using the SimpleDateFormat as I would loose the power of the locale based formatting.

So, anyone got any ideas how to make a minor change to the locale-formatted date?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Maybe Joda Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) can help you to fulfill both requirements (not an 'answer' because I never used Joda Time but most people love it)

Comment: Hmm, it seems using FieldPosition might help.

Comment: re: Joda time - It looks good, I might have to look further into that for this project.  Thanks.

Comment: Joda time is very good, I can highly recommend.  Last 5 years I haven't used the java.util.Date and friends at all (except for interfacing to APIs like JDBC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only straight-forward solution I have found is using FieldPosition:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
df.setTimeZone(User.getTimeZone());
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
FieldPosition fp = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.MINUTE_FIELD);
sb = df.format(d, sb, fp);
sb.insert( fp.getEndIndex(), new SimpleDateFormat(":ss").format(d) );
String s = sb.toString();
```

This is finding the position of the minute field in the string then allowing me to add the seconds straight after it.  The only real problems I can see with this, apart from it being a bit ugly, is that ":" might not be the correct separator and it might already have seconds in it.  So can anyone see a better answer?